# counting tags in HIVE

Tags: hive, bigdata

I have a column in hive called tags which has the data like :

```
tags-column  
c#  
C#,unix  
c++,templates,metaprogramming,debugging,  
c#,delegates,design,events  
unix,templates,events
```

how do i get the count of each tag?

For the above column result should me

```
c# 3  
unix 2  
templates 2  
metaprogramming 1  
debugging 1  
delegates 1  
design 1
events 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that you are looking [`LATERAL VIEW`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) in Hive.

This feature splits a given column and creates multiple rows with each token. You need to apply `GROUP BY` clause to get the count.

Sample HQL (Following is case sensitive, i.e. c# is not same as C#):

```
SELECT 
  single_tag,
  count(1) as cnt
FROM 
  tags_table LATERAL VIEW explode(split(tags_column, ',')) tag_table AS single_tag
GROUP BY 
  single_tag
ORDER BY
  cnt;
```

To make it case-insensitive, you can use `lower` or `upper` function. e.g.

```
SELECT 
  lower(single_tag), 
  count(1) as cnt
FROM 
  tags_table LATERAL VIEW explode(split(tags_column, ',')) tag_table AS single_tag
GROUP BY 
  lower(single_tag)
ORDER BY
  cnt;
```

Use [`split`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) to convert `String` to `Array<String>` field.

Comment: My tags-column is not array or map datatype...its a string datatype..So i dont think explode will work here..

Comment: My tags-column is not array or map datatype...its a string datatype..So i dont think explode will work here..  @Ambrish

Comment: I have tried it on string column and it is working. Can you give it a try.

Comment: UDFArgumentException explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter - It is showing this error @Ambrish

Comment: I have added an step to convert String to array. Try that

Comment: Well I think it worked not sure though but in any case can I order it by count? @Ambrish

Comment: Updated the answer with `order by` clause.

Comment: If this is what you are looking then accept the answer (upvote is a bonus).

Comment: thanks a lot...Now I see I need to learn lot more... It would be great if u can share ur linked profile :)  @Ambrish